# Can't find Class in IntelliJ IDEA but it worked in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

[image]

[image]

I can find the package im.onclick.insurance under the onclick-insurace-car-facade module but can't find it under the onclick-insurance-car-provider module.

But there is no problem in eclipse.

Comment: Try going to maven tab (on right side bar) and refreshing the maven project

Comment: try to run "mvn clean install" in the terminal (OR) go to "Maven project" window and run the clean & install from there.

Comment: Check [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085) for errors in case there was some issue with running Maven from IDEA and it didn't manage to download the dependencies.

Comment: just try a clean & build.